# System not terminating SSH session when my ISP disconnects

Tags: ssh, sshd

I have two ISP connections. The primary connection has got some disconnection issues these days. When the primary ISP does not respond, I switch to the backup internet connection and it supposed to disconnect the previous active SSH connections with the remote servers right?. But it does not happen in my case, instead, the terminal becomes frozen and hung, and it does not exit so that I cannot re-run the previous SSH command using the UP arrow key to reconnect quickly. This causes a bit of inconvenience for me to reconnect the server fast as I have to close the current terminal window, open a new one, re-type the SSH command.

I tried the following solution on my local SSH client-side but does not work.

```
 ^john> $ [.ssh] : pwd
/home/john/.ssh
 ^john> $ [.ssh] : cat config 
Host *
ServerAliveInterval 10
ServerAliveCountMax 1
```

Comment: Do you have the possibility of configuring the server? Try entering on the frozen SSH session the three keys `Enter`  `~` `.`.

Comment: It happens to any remote server that I connect to, so it is a local issue. Tried entering the three keys Enter ~ .  but nothing happens.

Comment: did you wait at least 10 secs (according to your config)? If so, then as far as ssh is concerned, the two are communicating. Are you doing anything special like tunneling, port forwarding, hopping? I'm not sure if related or not, but I also set `CheckHostIP no` which helps when DNS goes down. You could also try `ssh -vvv ...` to show the keep alive packets provided no other activity is occurring thru the connection.